# Running Appcelerator Titanium (for iPhone) in multiple accounts in mac

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I have installed the Titanium Developer 1.2.2 form my login account (on Mac system) and have done one demo project. I was able to see that working in the iPhone simulator. Now if I switch user and login to another account to run Titanium Developer there, it downloads and runs there but I am unable to launch any project there. The SDK Version simply shows as 'loading...'.

As a work around I opened a terminal window and typed `sudo abhilash` (assuming my login name is 'abhilash') and entered password and launched the Titanium from command line. It opened my instance of titanium and detected the SDK version properly as 4.2 and when I click launch in simulator, it throws the following error

[image: Error screenshot]

Now how do I make it working for the second user account? I have triend re-installing the xcode and titanium from the second user's account but no success :(

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't answer your question specifically but this post was helpful for me in enabling Titanium to be used across different user accounts. I suspect you may have already tried this  since I couldn't even get Titanium to open in another user account

http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/21121/titanium-crashing-on-startup-on-mac

the other thing to try is to create a new project in the new users account and then copy the contents of the "Resources" directory into the newly created project. I found this also fixed an issue of opening an old project.